# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'product' as it is null in a sanity ecommerce tutorial

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am following a [YouTube tutorial on creating an ecommerce website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mOkFXyxfsU), and I get and error at 1:28:11 saying Type Error: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'product' as it is null. I'll paste the code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'

import { client, urlFor } from '../../lib/client';

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
    const { image, name, details, price } = product;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='product-detail-container'>
                <div>
                    <div className='image-container'>
                        <img src={urlFor(image && image[0])} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const query = `*[_type == "product"] {
        slug {
            current
        }
    }
    `;

    const products = await client.fetch(query);

    const paths = products.map((product) => ({
        params: {
            slug: product.slug.current
        }
    }));

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking'
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug }}) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
    const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]'

    const product = await client.fetch(query);
    const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

    console.log(product);
  
    return {
      props: { products, product }
    }
  }

export default ProductDetails
```

I don't understand why it doesn't render the product image. its supposed to query the image from a sanity database.

Comment: sorry if code appears unreadable to you, this is my first time posting a question

Comment: From the error message you can conclude that the code fails at `const { image, name, details, price } = product;` line because `product` is `null`. You need to inspect places where `ProductDetails` is called, and observe what you pass in.

Comment: Is the line `console.log(product)` inside `getStaticProps` logging the expected output?